# Spring ajax send list of objects from controller to jsp

Tags: ajax, spring, jsp

I am trying to send send list of objects which I get from database to my JSP. I managed to successfully send data from JSP to my controller. Method inside my controller takes that parameter, fills List (I checked it in debug mode) and controller returns that list.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test.html", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody List<ModelVechicle> fetchListModelById(@RequestParam Integer number) {

    System.out.println(number);

    List<ModelVechicle> modelList = vechicleService.fetchModelById(number);

    return  modelList; 
}
```

When I try to get that List on my JSP, I get

```
HTTP Status 406 -

type Status report

message

description The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating 
responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
```

Here is my JSP with AJAX code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#brand").change(onSelectChange);
});

function onSelectChange() {
    var selected = $("#brand option:selected");     
    var output = "";
    var number = parseInt(selected.val());


      $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "test.html",
            dataType : 'json',
            data: ({number: number}),
             success: function(response){
                 $('#result').html("");
                    var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                    $('#result').html(obj.modelName);
                },
                error: function(xhr,e){                     
                    alert('Error while request..'+xhr.responseText);
                }
            });

    if(selected.val() != 0){
        output = "You selected brand " + selected.text();

    }
    $("#output").html(number);


}
```

Also here is my ModelVechicle class, that is the class which objects I am adding into List:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CARDEALERSHIP.MODEL")
public class ModelVechicle implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7420515051961158192L;

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
private Integer modelId;

@Column(name = "MODELNAME")
private String modelName;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "BRANDID")
private Brand brand;

public ModelVechicle(Integer modelId, String modelName, Brand brand) {
    super();
    this.modelId = modelId;
    this.modelName = modelName;
    this.brand = brand;
}

public ModelVechicle() {}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((brand == null) ? 0 : brand.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((modelId == null) ? 0 : modelId.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((modelName == null) ? 0 : modelName.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    ModelVechicle other = (ModelVechicle) obj;
    if (brand == null) {
        if (other.brand != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!brand.equals(other.brand))
        return false;
    if (modelId == null) {
        if (other.modelId != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!modelId.equals(other.modelId))
        return false;
    if (modelName == null) {
        if (other.modelName != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!modelName.equals(other.modelName))
        return false;
    return true;
}

public Integer getModelId() {
    return modelId;
}

public void setModelId(Integer modelId) {
    this.modelId = modelId;
}

public String getModelName() {
    return modelName;
}

public void setModelName(String modelName) {
    this.modelName = modelName;
}

public Brand getBrand() {
    return brand;
}

public void setBrand(Brand brand) {
    this.brand = brand;
}
```

Can somebody please explain me what to do in order to get the List dynamically to JSP page, and display List members properly?

EDIT: Here is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>CarDealership</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>addVechicle.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatchers.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/app-config.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Which version of Spring framework are you using?

Comment: @jlumietu 4.2.6.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Spring 3.2+, the content negotiation has other facts in account prior to eval `Accept` header:

From https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc:

> **Enabling Content Negotiation in Spring MVC**
>
> Spring supports a couple of conventions for selecting the format
>   required: URL suffixes and/or a URL parameter. These work alongside
>   the use of Accept headers. As a result, the content-type can be
>   requested in any of three ways. By default they are checked in this
>   order:
>
> - Add a path extension (suffix) in the URL. So, if the incoming URL is something like http://myserver/myapp/accounts/list.html then HTML
>     is required. For a spreadsheet the URL should be
>     http://myserver/myapp/accounts/list.xls. The suffix to media-type
>     mapping is automatically defined via the JavaBeans Activation
>     Framework or JAF (so activation.jar must be on the class path).
> - A URL parameter like this: http://myserver/myapp/accounts/list?format=xls. The name of the
>     parameter is format by default, but this may be changed. Using a
>     parameter is disabled by default, but when enabled, it is checked
>     second.
> - Finally the Accept HTTP header property is checked. This is how HTTP is  > actually defined to work, but, as previously mentioned, it can
>     be problematic to use.

That actually means that if you map a `@Controller` method with a `.htm(l)` suffix, it is intended to return `html` and won't return `json` nor any other format even if you sent other format as `Accept` header.

I allways map my controllers as `.htm` and had to change the way I used to map `@ResponseBody` annotated methods when I upgraded to Spring 3.2 and newer.

**EDIT:**
After seeing your web.xml, as I supposed, you are mapping every .html suffix request to the dispatcher servlet:

```
  `<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>`
```

I figure that now the `@RequestMapping` in your controller is like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody List<ModelVechicle> fetchListModelById(@RequestParam Integer number) {
```

As `/test` does not match `.html` suffix, request is not arriving to springDispatcher, and that's exactly why you are getting a 404.

Now, options to fix this:

1) Add a new mapping in the web.xml which matches this controller:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*/test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This way you would be forced to include any new non html returning method. Not seems usable for me.

2) Map all incoming requests  to dispatcherServlet

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

I don't really like this option, I prefer to filter what I really want to reach the dispatcher servlet.

3) Find a new matching pattern for this kind of requests. I allways publish some kind of generic suffix, which will not be catched by JAF, such as *.service:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.service</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

So in Controller methods which return XML or JSON (or any other format, depending only of the `Accept` header), I map like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test.service", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody List<ModelVechicle> fetchListModelById(@RequestParam Integer number) {
```

4) You could as well publish all this kind of @ResponseBody controller method using a 'http://com.xxx.yyy/myApp/service/resource' pattern and use `/service/` as servlet mapping in web.xml

```
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/service/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: now I have new one:

    HTTP Status 404 - /CarDealership/test

    type Status report

    message /CarDealership/test

    description The requested resource is not available.

I guess View resorlver is trying to resolve the "/test" into jsp, but I want to stay on the same page, and dynamically send the List to current JSP page.

Comment: Show your web.xml please

Comment: works like a charm now. Thank you very much for detailed explanation. We used to work with these .html extensions and didn't have the need to do it otherwise. But since I grabbed the hold on AJAX it is now a life saviour. You regained my confidence and faith in humanity :)

Comment: First time I made an upgrade to spring 3.2 I nearly became mad when all the working ajax actions suddenly started returning Http 400... glad it worked!