# How to send list from controller and accept json in jsp

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jsp

I want to display that list in json format. When I run this code, it does not display any data in json format but gets in other format. How to display that list?

Controller class

```
@Controller
public class RoomController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView saveEmployee(){ 
    System.out.println("welcome");
  return new ModelAndView("NewFile","message","hello");
 }
@RequestMapping(value="ViewMember",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<RoomMembers> getRoomMembers() {
    System.out.println("second test");
    List<RoomMembers> roomMemberList= new ArrayList<RoomMembers>();
    roomMemberList=roomDao.listMember();
    return roomMemberList;
}
```

Jsp file is

```
<head>
<title>Spring MVC Ajax Demo</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doAjax() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/RoomController/ViewMember',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
    var roommember=JSON.parse(data);;
      $('#time').html(roommember);
    }
  });
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="demo" onclick="doAjax()" title="Button">Get the time!</button>
<div id="time">
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are requesting the wrong url. In the script in your jsp, the url passed do `$.ajax()` is url `/RoomController/ViewMember.html`. But in your controller you have mapped ir as simply 'ViewMember'

```
@RequestMapping(value="ViewMember",method=RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
```

Try requesting just `/RoomController/ViewMember` and let's us know wether it works or not.

**EDIT**:

You say that .html url gets called and that you are using Spring 4.0.6, and that you get a `HTTP 406 (NOTACCEPTABLE)` response.

First check if you are sending Accept header as `"application/json"`. But you won't be able to receive an HTTP 200 with json response in a controller mapped with `".html"`/`".htm"` in a Spring MVC Controller with Spring 3.2 or above. From https://stackoverflow.com/a/39479308/4190848:

> As of Spring 3.2+, the content negotiation has other facts in account prior to eval `Accept` header:
>
> From [https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39479308/4190848):
>
> > **Enabling Content Negotiation in Spring MVC**
> >
> > Spring supports a couple of conventions for selecting the format
> >     required: URL suffixes and/or a URL parameter. These work alongside
> >     the use of Accept headers. As a result, the content-type can be
> >     requested in any of three ways. By default they are checked in this
> >     order:
> >
> > - Add a path extension (suffix) in the URL. So, if the incoming URL is something like http://myserver/myapp/accounts/list.html then HTML
> >       is required. For a spreadsheet the URL should be
> >       http://myserver/myapp/accounts/list.xls. The suffix to media-type
> >       mapping is automatically defined via the JavaBeans Activation
> >       Framework or JAF (so activation.jar must be on the class path).
> > - A URL parameter like this: http://myserver/myapp/accounts/list?format=xls. The name of the
> >       parameter is format by default, but this may be changed. Using a
> >       parameter is disabled by default, but when enabled, it is checked
> >       second.
> > - Finally the Accept HTTP header property is checked. This is how HTTP is  > actually defined to work, but, as previously mentioned, it
> >       can
> >       be problematic to use.
>
> That actually means that if you map a `@Controller` method with a
>   `.htm(l)` suffix, it is intended to return `html` and won't return
>   `json` nor any other format even if you sent other format as `Accept`
>   header.
>   ...

So change your mapping to other suffix than ".html"/".htm" (or use no suffix) and you will solve your error

Comment: but  getRoomMembers() method is executed and print second test in my console

Comment: Which spring version are you using? 3.2 or above?

Comment: Please provide Http response status of the ajax call and what it returns as body in case it actually returns something

Comment: 406 (Not Acceptable).

Comment: It won't work. That's what I was trying to explain. Both ".html" and ".htm" are related to html response type, so they allways will return HTTP 406 when asking for json, xml or any other accept media type

Comment: I already explained it. Call `/RoomController/ViewMember`  without ".html" suffix.

Answer (score 0):

the url in ajax is wrong,you should write "ViewMember".